# How to create an html table with captions for column and row sections

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make an html table similar to this:

[image]

I'm not interested in the data for the table but just the barebones: Likelihood, Consequence, column names (minor, moderate, etc) and rows (almost certain, likely, etc).

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/PQHR6/

I can't figure out how to make those `Likelihood` and `Consequence` headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `th` with the attribute `colspan`.

```
    <tr>
        <th>Table header</th>
        <th colspan="5">Table header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp; <!-- EMPTY --></th>
        <th>Minor</th>
        <th>Lorem 1</th>
        <th>Lorem 2</th>
        <th>Lorem 3</th>
        <th>Lorem 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Almost Certain</th>
        <td>Table cell 1</td>
        <td>Table cell 2</td>
        <td>Table cell 3</td>
        <td>Table cell 4</td>
        <td>Table cell 5</td>
    </tr>
```

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPQfz/**

Comment: I had the same problem, and colspan solved it. But all <td> have the same width, how to change that?

Answer (score 1):

Use table headings `th` and add `colspan` attribute to second heading to span 5 columns:

```
<tr>
    <th>Likelyhood</th>
    <th colspan="5">Consequence</th>
</tr>
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQHR6/2/)

Comment: With a complex table like this it's also helpful (from an accessibility standpoint) to add the `scope` attribute to the `th` elements (`scope="row/col"`).